# How can I use cassandra driver for Node.js in an Angular 7 project using Typescript

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, cassandra

Starting from the oficial tutorial for Angular "Tour of Heroes", im trying to add code in typescript to query a cassandra database using the official Node.js driver.
But i cant make it work.
Any body have an example project for this?

Im using two tipes of solutions. Importing the Nodejs driver in angular, and execute a Nodejs script in angular.

I tested the NOdejs driver in a simple script and worked fine.

Thanks for the comments.

Comment: I think it is not possible to use cassandra driver within Angular, since Angular runs inside browser, which is different environment than nodejs.

Comment: So how should i do it? create some service in the backend and angular call it?

Comment: Yes, you need to use nodejs based backend with api for front-end (angular)